# Свойство интерфейса из класса typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Как указать ts брать имя свойства интерфейса из экземпляра класса, который нужно найти по ключу из значения другого свойства?

```
class A {aaa: number = 1;}
class B {bbb: number = 2;}
class C {ccc: number = 3;}

interface I {
    qwerty: A;
    abcde: B;
    zzz: C;
}

interface Test<T extends keyof I, K = I[T]> {
    test1: T;
    [M: keyof K]: K[typeof M]; // typeof K[M] ???
}

function load<T extends keyof I>(test: Test<T>): void {}

load({
    test1: 'abcde',
    bbb: 50, // Argument of type '{ test1: "abcde"; bbb: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Test<"abcde", B>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bbb' does not exist in type 'Test<"abcde", B>'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо интерфейса нужно использовать [`mapped types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```
type Test<T extends keyof I, K = I[T]> = {
    test1: T;
} & {
    [M in keyof K]: K[M]; 
}
```

В этом случае к обязательному полю `test1` добавляются все поля соответствующего класса

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8zIFzQHYFcC2AjApgE7QC80AjANwC+AUKJDAEKK5tpZ5GnQBMN9cFGgBhRMAkccBYmQDMA2gEt0AFyIAzMMHzQAkolrRj0AI4B3IqoCeaWJSMmwuYABN8aJg5PQAXv7QRBzpaGwAHXQAVfAhVAB5I6HwAD3V0VxgAa3xrAHsNfQAaaABpHj0AbUiAXQA+HgRHY3VY8jRI4OgAMkMfCoBZaBVobLyCkuq0EoHqymgAennocPx80pnoAH5t2hCNTHRgVSVc9GgQXLBXBKTU-HSsnLW9WoAKFtV2mPjI2oBKNAAN1ySlciBCFyur0aPg+bWgAHJnG58AjCk1oGxcGgAKwABmKizghAA5jh7qpoGsVoiEMtvvCAETI9yMuZYqRcQhzagIoYwdC5SmMJQk9DOEC6VS5aBhMCEMDYfDqYjU6wRRHRWJxZkuVnFJi1BEAOmgAHlcAArfBHc5KFVgEDQbBgaxU9AgN0QCLAJQaN2ZQXmM5hQi5CKEY4xYpgdKIrF81y5GIYIW3JSxIZnGkIrXxXUoxkGo27P6UIA)

Comment: `K` можно не выносить в generic.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно

Answer (score -1):

Воспользуйтесь type guards, например:

```
class A {
  aaa = 1;
  kind: 'typeA' = 'typeA';
}
class B {
  bbb = 2;
  kind: 'typeB' = 'typeB';
}

function load(test: A | B) {
  if (test.kind === 'typeA') {
    console.log(test.aaa);
  } else {
    console.log(test.bbb);
  }
}

load({
  aaa: 2,
  kind: 'typeA',
});
```